# Assign a string value as a result of a command

Tags: debugging, windbg, breakpoints

I want to put a string result of a command in WinDbg in a variable for a later use.

For example, in a memory breakpointI want to save the result of - `lm1ma eip` that returns me the current module, for later comparison in `$spat` command.

If anyone knows a better way to achieve the goal of determining if the current debugged module is a specific module, inside a conditional breakpoint, it could be also helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as /c Name CommandString`.
It creates an alias to the results of executing the specified command.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/as--as--set-alias-